# Remove an array from object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I call an API in response show an array in an object like this i share screen shot below

[image]

I want to remove the filter keyword in an activities object and rest of the response is same how i could do this.
Please help Thanks in advance.

Here is my code below:

```
public function index(FilterRequest $request)
{
    $data = $this->filter($request);
    $mapsData = $data->original;

    return response()->json(['activities'=> $mapsData], 200);
}
```

Comment: You should look at Eloquent resources, especially the examples with the `toArray` functions. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources

Comment: The only way I can think of it would be to create a variable and store what data you need in it, however creating/storing a variable takes up memory on a server and when you're talking efficient code do you really need to?  If you are not going to use the filter array just don't use it.  Why do you not want it there?

Comment: You can simply `unset()` `filters`. If `$mapsData` is an `array()`, you can simple do `unset($mapsData["filters"])`. But it's recommended to do it earlier in the chain.

Comment: because the app wants that response thats why i do not want the filter

Comment: In where ican use this unset ? @Angua

Comment: Above your return: `$mapsData = unset($mapsData["filters"]);`

Comment: unset returns void? @Nieck

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET) shows that error

Answer (score 1):

you can use except method in laravel collections

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-except

Comment: something like this :
`$filtered = $mapsData ->except(['filter']);`

`return $filtered->all();`

Comment: that removes the whole filter array but i only want to remove the filter keyword and rest of the response is same

Comment: No, this removes only filter keyword

Comment: but this removes all the reponse only show this activities:[]

Comment: I probably can help you if you can put your exported json file here

Comment: exported json file ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index(FilterRequest $request)
{

    $data = $this->filter($request);
    $mapsData = $data->original;

    return response()->json(['activities'=> $mapsData['filter']], 200);
}
```